# Jquery Ui tooltip shows only one word

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I am using jqueryUi  to display tool tip for a image. I see only first word in tooltip. What may be the issue? Withe below code I see tool tip as "High" instead of "High priority".

```
return "<img title=High Priority src=@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.High_png) />";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the quotes around the `title` and `src` attributes.

change this

```
return "<img title=High Priority src=@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.High_png) />";
```

to this

```
return "<img title='High Priority' src='@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.High_png)' />";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me on my silly mistake. I am just ashamed of myself.

Comment: We all make mistakes, don't worry about it

Comment: Delimiters in HTML are `"` not single qoutes. Cheers. Edited. Check HTML rules.